# Duda con cstring y string

Tags: c++

No tengo muy clara la diferencia entre la libreria cstring y la libreria string.
Según entiendo, la cabecera string es, como su nombre indica, para tipos string, mientras que cstring es para usar sus funciones con tipo char.

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar si es Cstring de MFC de visual studio o si estás haciendo un `#include <cstring>`? Es que las respuestas que te están dando están enfocadas hacia lo segundo, pero ninguna hacia lo primero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La librería `cstring` (también accesible vía `string.h`) es una librería importada de C. Dado que C no es un lenguaje orientado a objetos, está enfocada al trabajo con arreglos de tipo `char*`. Así, encontramos funciones como:

- `strcpy`: Copia una cadena de texto
- `strlen`: Longitud de una cadena de texto
- `strcat`: Concatena dos cadenas de texto

La librería `string` es propia de C++. Esta librería gira en torno a la clase `std::string` que viene a ser el sustituto natural de `char*`. Las ventajas de usar esta clase sobre `char*` son varias:

- Te despreocupas de la gestión de la memoria dinámica
- No es necesario gestionar buffers propios (p. ej: `char buffer[500]`)
- No tiene limitaciones de capacidad
- Es compatible con `char*` vía función `string.c_str()`

La clase `string`, simplificando mucho, lo que hace es encapsular un puntero de tipo `char` y gestionar su ciclo de vida. Permite escribir código de forma más rápida, más segura ya que, por ejemplo, evita que se escriba fuera de la memoria reservada a tal efecto, y más legible.

Un ejemplo de legibilidad:

```
char* charFunc(const char* cadena1, int numero)
{
  size_t len = strlen(cadena1);
  len += log10(numero) + 1; // Número de dígitos del número
  len += 1; // Espacio para el caracter '\0'
  char* ptr = new char[](len);

  if( ptr )
    sprintf(ptr,"%s%d",cadena1,numero);

  return ptr;
}

std::string stringFunc(const std::string& cadena1, int numero)
{
  return cadena1 + std::to_string(numero);
} 

int main()
{
  // Versión char*
  char* cadena1 = charFunc("Una prueba",10);
  std::cout << cadena1 << '\n';
  delete[] cadena1;

  // Versión string
  std::string cadena2 = stringFunc("Una prueba",10);
  std::cout << cadena2 << '\n';
  // No necesita delete
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El encabezado cstring tiene funciones para tratar cadenas de estilo C, funciones como strlen y strcpy

El encabezado de string proporciona la clase std :: string y las funciones y operadores relacionados.

Los encabezados tienen nombres similares, pero no están realmente relacionados más allá de eso. Cubren tareas separadas.